# Unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 6 are not supported! - causes importing cpp_extension

Tags: c++, gcc, pytorch

Then I import it says before error this:

```
/home/dex/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py:118: UserWarning: 

                               !! WARNING !!

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Your compiler (c++) may be ABI-incompatible with PyTorch!
Please use a compiler that is ABI-compatible with GCC 4.9 and above.
See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html.

See https://gist.github.com/goldsborough/d466f43e8ffc948ff92de7486c5216d6
for instructions on how to install GCC 4.9 or higher.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

                              !! WARNING !!

  warnings.warn(ABI_INCOMPATIBILITY_WARNING.format(compiler))
```

But following gist  trying to install 4.9 and 5.9 same errors
Cant get installed, also on 18.04 but with other error:

```
  dex@dexpc:~$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
[sudo] password for dex: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
software-properties-common is already the newest version (0.96.24.32.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
dex@dexpc:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]     
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
Hit:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]   
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
dex@dexpc:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc-5.9 g++-5.9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-5.9
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gcc-5.9'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-5.9'
E: Unable to locate package g++-5.9
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'g++-5.9'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'g++-5.9'




dex@dexpc:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0
```

Comment: You have two completely separate problems here. One is support in PyTorch, for which you provide the answer in the question. The other is an inability to install newer GCC on your Ubuntu. For that, you need to Google "install GCC Ubuntu" for which I'm seeing many relevant results.

Comment: Overall I would consult the PyTorch mailing list and ask others who have gone down this route on your OS.

Comment: Have never used PyTorch but a quick scan of their issues database revealed [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/10114); relevant?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have to install abi compatible version - which is not easy for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two steps to fix the problem:

1)
There should be a copy of sources.list at  /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list   Copy your /etc/apt/sources.list to save the ppa changes you entered and start with the fresh copy.  Then run the

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then add in your ppas from your saved copy of sources list, and repeat the

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Just in case, here's the contents of the fresh file:

```
# See sources.list(5) manpage for more information
# Remember that CD-ROMs, DVDs and such are managed through the apt-cdrom tool.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
```

2) To get rif off obsolete ppa

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:armagetronad-dev/ppa 
sudo apt update -q
```